# Using Multiple useState hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

In React Native project to get input data in form I have used multiple hooks. Is there any better or efficient way to do so?

thanks

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');
const [rollNo, setRollNo] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
```

Comment: Use a single `useReducer`.

Comment: You can, you can also use an object instead (depending on how generic the logic is and how DRY you want the code to be)

Comment: The `useReducer` hook is a good idea but typically for forms I try to use `formik` or some other form management library that also comes with some structure for submitting and validating input.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the correct way to do it. Simple states are a good way to use them. I believe it's better practice to not use `''` as initial state but `null`. So that there is no confusion possible.

Comment: Inputs are string so that's why I used `''` . Yeah it's better to use `null` as initial state. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. Better use `useReducer`

```
import { useReducer } from "react";

const studentInitState = {
  name: null,
  surname: null,
  rollNo: null,
  phone: null,
  email: null
};

function Test(props) {
  const [student, setStudent] = useReducer(
    //--> below line implies. that take old state & update the current state and return the `new state`  this is called a `Reducer` function.
    (student, newDetails) => ({ ...student, ...newDetails }),

    studentInitState
  );


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setStudent({ name: "Sachin" })}>Update</button>
      {student.name}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: This is the better way instead using multiple hooks, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use useReducer hook or you can also use custom [useSetState](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useSetState.md) which which works similar to how this.setState works in class components. It merges object changes into current state.

If the data received from the back-end API is an object containing the user details such as name and email etc etc... then you should not have separate state variables for each and every property. Instead you should save the entire user object in a single state variable. If you need you can de-structure it later like so:

```
const User = ({ props }) => {
  // good
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const { name, email } = user;

  //bad
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
};
```

Comment: better, I'll implement this. Thanks!